# using emacs for visudo editor not opening /etc/sudoers file on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, emacs, sudo

I would like to use `emacs` to edit my `sudoers` file using `visudo` on my Mac, but for the life of me, I can't get it to happen. I've tried all of the following configuration settings in the `sudoers` file, to no avail:

- `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/emacs"` shows the `emacs` intro screen
- `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/emacs visudo"` creates new file named "visudo"
- `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/emacs sudoers"` opens the sudoers file, but as a read-only buffer
- running `EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs"` in the shell (or `export`ing it to my `~/.bash_profile` file), then running `visudo` with `Defaults env_keep+="EDITOR"` shows the `emacs` intro screen
- `Defaults editor = "emacs"` says the `editor` variable must start with `/`
- `Defaults editor = /usr/bin/emacs` shows the intro screen
- `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/emacs -u matt"` shows the intro screen

Basically, nothing I do works. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running macOS High Sierra (10.13).

Comment: according to `man visudo` (on ubuntu) visudo will use `/usr/bin/editor` (which go to /bin/nano), have you ckecked this ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/editor` doesn’t exist on a Mac

Comment: too bad ! :( I didn't bother to check my mac must be 10.3 ...

Comment: Are you using `sudo visudo`? If not, you won't have permission to write the file.

Comment: @Barmar yup I’m definitely doing that :P

Comment: Does [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130171/using-visudo-to-edit-sudoers-on-mac) help?

Comment: @harrymc nope, sorry :/

Comment: See this : [another possibility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `visudo` runs `emacs` like this: `/usr/bin/emacs -- /etc/sudoers.tmp`. Emacs doesn't interpret '--' as 'end of arguments' and  everything after it as filenames like other editors, but shows the intro screen instead. The easiest way around this I know of is a wrapper:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo cat > /usr/bin/emacs-visudo-wrapper.sh << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
ARGS=()
for var in "$@"; do
   [ "$var" != '--' ] && ARGS+=("$var")
done
exec /usr/bin/emacs "${ARGS[@]}"
EOF
bash-3.2$ sudo chown root:wheel /usr/bin/emacs-visudo-wrapper.sh
bash-3.2$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/emacs-visudo-wrapper.sh
bash-3.2$ sudo cat >> /etc/sudoers << 'EOF'
Defaults    editor = "/usr/bin/emacs-visudo-wrapper.sh"
EOF
```